# PHP Tried to get return value in sprintf

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I am trying to output placeholder attribute value but i am tried a lot as spend 8 hours for this case, kindly check this issue below.

My function:

```
if ( $tag->has_option( 'placeholder' ) or $tag->has_option( 'watermark' ) ) {
    $atts['placeholder'] = $value;
    $forplaceholder['placeholder'] = $value;
    $value = '';
}

$forplaceholder = wpcf7_format_atts( $forplaceholder);

$html = sprintf(
    '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %4$s">%1$s<input %2$s />%3$s</span>',
    sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error, $forplaceholder
);
```

In this case i am getting out for %4$s `placeholder="something"`

Example output: `<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap placeholder="something"">`

How do i get value as `something` instated of `placeholder="something"`?

Comment: Not sure of the code, but looks like you just want the value of the placeholder and not formatted -  try `$forplaceholder['placeholder']` in the `sprintf()` (possibly with `?? ''` in case it's not set.)

Comment: Yes your absolutely correct. Just want the value of the placeholder and not formatted. I have added in sprintf but no result. Anyway, where i have added `?? ''` ?

Comment: @NigelRen, would you please explain a bit? It will help much.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you want something like

```
$html = sprintf(
    '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %4$s">%1$s<input %2$s />%3$s</span>',
    sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error, 
    $forplaceholder['placeholder'] ?? ''
);
```

Using `$forplaceholder['placeholder']` as this puts the actual value rather than encoding it using `wpcf7_format_atts()`.  The `?? ''` means that if the value isn't set, it won't throw an error and just put a blank value in.

Comment: Love you. I have adjusted now.